# Copy specific value and paste into specific cells of another sheet in Google Sheet based on condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a table in following structure in "Sheet1".

[image]

```
Date         CQ %    LR%     UD %    DP %   DSI %    UB %   DDD %
26-Feb-2017 0.49%   0.15%   0.37%   0.53%   0.31%   0.82%   4.09%
27-Feb-2017 0.51%   0.12%   0.46%   0.71%   0.36%   0.91%   4.06%
28-Feb-2017 0.56%   0.18%   0.50%   0.72%   0.33%   0.93%   3.28%
1-Mar-2017  0.62%   0.13%   0.42%   0.75%   0.34%   0.94%   5.08%
2-Mar-2017  0.59%   0.12%   0.42%   0.76%   0.35%   0.99%   5.12%
3-Mar-2017  0.62%   0.13%   0.50%   0.80%   0.32%   0.91%   5.33%
4-Mar-2017  0.72%   0.22%   0.52%   1.49%   0.37%   1.08%   4.05%
5-Mar-2017  0.68%   0.17%   0.43%   0.74%   0.35%   1.01%   4.76%
6-Mar-2017  0.63%   0.18%   0.55%   0.88%   0.38%   1.02%   4.88%
7-Mar-2017  0.56%   0.19%   0.41%   0.75%   0.33%   0.91%   4.76%
```

In "Sheet 2" the value from "Sheet1" will be copied on and pasted on a specific format and condition mentioned below.

```
Condition (>=)

CQ %    LR%    UD%     DP%    DSI%   UB%    DDD%  Rating
0.58%  0.17%  0.47%   0.75%   0.35%  0.93%  4.50%  4.57
```

Format in which it will be copied

```
Date        Metric    Value
27-02-2017   DSI      0.36%
28-02-2017   CQ       0.56%
28-02-2017   LR       0.18%
28-02-2017   UD       0.50%
28-02-2017   UB       0.93% 
01-03-2017   CQ       0.62%
01-03-2017   DP       0.75%
01-03-2017   UB       0.94% etc
```

Comment: Table image is attached in picture format

Comment: On the second line of your formatted output you have `28-02-2017   CQ       0.56%` but isn't the condition for CQ supposed to be >= 0.56%

Comment: Yes the condition will be >=0.56%. Its a mistake done from my side while typing. Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Is the sheet 2 column "rating" used in any way?

Comment: Thanks Cooper: Its worked like a charm!!!! Its helped me a lot. Thanks Cooper. God bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Selecting Data with Criteria stored in an Associative Array

I created three pages Data, Criteria and Output.  I used an associative array to hold the criteria on the 'Criteria' sheet and I used the keys for the associative array as headers for the data table on the 'Data' Sheet. Finally, I obtained the size of the final output range by using the height of the outputA array and the necessary 3 columns of output.

```
function listSelectedValues()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var crit=ss.getSheetByName('Criteria')
  var dataA=data.getDataRange().getValues();
  var critA=crit.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dictA={};
  var outputA=[];
  var outputS=ss.getSheetByName('Output');
  for(var i=0;i<critA[0].length;i++)
  {
    dictA[critA[0][i]]=critA[1][i];  //this builds a criteria dictionary or lookup table
  }
  /* This is just debugging stuff to make sure I got the associative array correct and yes I did include the rating but it's not one of the columns so it never gets used.
  var s='{';
  var firstTime=true;
  for(var key in dictA)
  {
    if(!firstTime)s+=',';
    else firstTime=false;
    s+=key + ':' + dictA[key];
  }
  s+='}'
  dispStatus('dictA',s,800,600);
  */
  for(var i=1;i<dataA.length;i++)//skip over the dates i starts at 1
  {
    for(var j=1;j<dataA[i].length;j++)//skip over the keys j starts at 1
    {
      if(dataA[i][j]>=dictA[dataA[0][j]])//this is possible because I used column headers that are keys in the associative array (dictA)
      {
        outputA.push([dataA[i][0],dataA[0][j],dataA[i][j]]); //notice the extra array bracket for inserting an entire row and insuring a 2 dimensional array for the coming setValues command.
      }
    }
  }
  var outputR=outputS.getRange(1, 1, outputA.length, 3);
  outputR.setValues(outputA);
}
```

You'll probably want to modify this so that you can make the header row more meaningful to you audience but then that will complicate the use of the header elements as keys to the associative array.  Whenever possible I choose the path of least resistance.

I included the dispStatus routine that I used.

```
function dispStatus(title,html,width,height,modal)
{
  var title = typeof(title) !== 'undefined' ? title : 'No Title Provided';
  var width = typeof(width) !== 'undefined' ? width : 400;
  var height = typeof(height) !== 'undefined' ? height : 300;
  var html = typeof(html) !== 'undefined' ? html : '<p>No html provided.</p>';
  var modal = typeof(modal) !== 'undefined' ? modal : false;
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput(html)
     .setWidth(width)
     .setHeight(height);
 if(!modal)
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
 else
 {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, title);
 }
}
```

Final Output with no formating looks like this.

```
2/27/2017   DSI 0.36
2/28/2017   LR  0.18
2/28/2017   UD  0.5
2/28/2017   UB  0.93
3/1/2017    CQ  0.62
3/1/2017    DP  0.75
3/1/2017    UB  0.94
3/1/2017    DDD 5.08
3/2/2017    CQ  0.59
3/2/2017    DP  0.76
3/2/2017    DSI 0.35
3/2/2017    UB  0.99
3/2/2017    DDD 5.12
3/3/2017    CQ  0.62
3/3/2017    UD  0.5
3/3/2017    DP  0.8
3/3/2017    DDD 5.33
3/4/2017    CQ  0.72
3/4/2017    LR  0.22
3/4/2017    UD  0.52
3/4/2017    DP  1.49
3/4/2017    DSI 0.37
3/4/2017    UB  1.08
3/5/2017    CQ  0.68
3/5/2017    LR  0.17
3/5/2017    DSI 0.35
3/5/2017    UB  1.01
3/5/2017    DDD 4.76
3/6/2017    CQ  0.63
3/6/2017    LR  0.18
3/6/2017    UD  0.55
3/6/2017    DP  0.88
3/6/2017    DSI 0.38
3/6/2017    UB  1.02
3/6/2017    DDD 4.88
3/7/2017    LR  0.19
3/7/2017    DP  0.75
3/7/2017    DDD 4.76
```

I hope this is helpful to you.

Okay I added the final twist into the equation with this version.

```
function listSelectedValues()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var crit=ss.getSheetByName('Criteria')
  var dataA=data.getDataRange().getValues();
  var critA=crit.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dictA={};
  var outputA=[];
  var outputS=ss.getSheetByName('Output');
  for(var i=0;i<critA[0].length;i++)
  {
    dictA[critA[0][i]]=critA[1][i];  //this build a criteria dictionary or lookup table
  }
  for(var i=1;i<dataA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=1;j<dataA[i].length;j++)
    {

      if((j<dataA[i].length-1)&&(dataA[i][j]>=dictA[dataA[0][j]])||((j=dataA[i].length-1)&&(dataA[i][j]<dictA[dataA[0][j]])))
      {
        outputA.push([dataA[i][0],dataA[0][j],dataA[i][j]]); 
      }
    }
  }
  var outputR=outputS.getRange(1, 1, outputA.length, 3);
  outputR.setValues(outputA);
  var end = 'is near';
}
```

This is my test data.

```
Date    CQ  LR  UD  DP  DSI UB  DDD Rating
26-Feb-2017 0.49    0.15    0.37    0.53    0.31    0.82    4.09    5.00
27-Feb-2017 0.51    0.12    0.46    0.71    0.36    0.91    4.06    4.90
28-Feb-2017 0.56    0.18    0.5 0.72    0.33    0.93    3.28    4.80
1-Mar-2017  0.62    0.13    0.42    0.75    0.34    0.94    5.08    4.70
2-Mar-2017  0.59    0.12    0.42    0.76    0.35    0.99    5.12    4.60
3-Mar-2017  0.62    0.13    0.5 0.8 0.32    0.91    5.33    4.50
4-Mar-2017  0.72    0.22    0.52    1.49    0.37    1.08    4.05    4.40
5-Mar-2017  0.68    0.17    0.43    0.74    0.35    1.01    4.76    4.30
6-Mar-2017  0.63    0.18    0.55    0.88    0.38    1.02    4.88    4.20
7-Mar-2017  0.56    0.19    0.41    0.75    0.33    0.91    4.76    4.10
```

This is my output

```
3/1/2017    CQ  0.62
3/2/2017    CQ  0.59
3/3/2017    CQ  0.62
3/3/2017    Rating  4.50
3/4/2017    CQ  0.72
3/4/2017    LR  0.22
3/4/2017    UD  0.52
3/4/2017    DP  1.49
3/4/2017    DSI 0.37
3/4/2017    UB  1.08
3/4/2017    Rating  4.40
3/5/2017    CQ  0.68
3/5/2017    LR  0.17
3/5/2017    Rating  4.30
3/6/2017    CQ  0.63
3/6/2017    LR  0.18
3/6/2017    UD  0.55
3/6/2017    DP  0.88
3/6/2017    DSI 0.38
3/6/2017    UB  1.02
3/6/2017    DDD 4.88
3/6/2017    Rating  4.20
3/7/2017    Rating  4.10
```

Comment: I am getting the below mentioned error. The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 37, file "Code"). Please guide.

Comment: I gather from your other comment that you have resolved this issue.  If not, then please repost your current code so I can take a look at it because I can't reproduce the problem.  It is common however to have problems with range size when dealing with setValues() command.

Comment: Well Cooper there is little twist . The condition of Rating will be <=4.57. How to incorporate ?

Comment: I have no data for the rating. Is it calculated? If so, how? Or do you have additional data not yet shown?  I have nothing to compare to the 4.57.

Comment: Rating is the last column after DDD% which need to be compared. The condition is less than 4.57. The same is implemented few days ago. So it is not given in the data earlier. So the fact is that after DDD% their will be another column of Rating and the condition will be less than 4.57 instead of greater than. The output will be same.

Comment: Can you also look into this that I have posted below. "Sending Automated formatted mail with image in the body of mail from google spreadsheet".

Comment: I recommend posting the email question as a separate question.

Comment: Its posted as separate question. Below is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092375/sending-automated-formatted-mail-with-image-in-the-body-of-mail-from-google-spre

Comment: I don't do much scripting with email. If you want to be a programmer there are some questions your just going to have to figure out on your own.  Sometimes I take a step back and try to work on simpler but related problems before returning to the more difficult problems.  In the end, conquering a difficult problem is a very rewarding experience I would encourage you to give yourself the opportunity to experience that feeling.