# Sending Automated formatted mail with image in the body of mail from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api, email

I maintain one sheet("Data") which has the following fields.

Name      Date_of_Joining    Email_Id                 Date_of_Birth     Status.
Jagmeet   29-03-2016      Jagmeet.biswas@gmail.com    31st March 1975   Active

I maintain another sheet("Mail_ID") which has the email id of all the users
Name                        Email_ID
Kaushik Bose           Kaushik.Bose@gmail.com
Raj Karmakar           raj.karmakar@gmail.com

On 31st March one email will go to Jagmeet with bcc to other employees from "Mail ID" sheet in below mentioned format.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbJp7.png)

Please help!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you asking us to do the work for you? ; )

Comment: No I am asking for help. Since most of the syntax is not known to me. Thanks

Comment: noogui Please help